# Extract Number from string "times_series_graphs 34"

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have a list of graphs from 1 to 34 named "times_series_graphs 1", times_series_graphs 2", "times_series_graphs 3" etc all the way up to 34.

is there a way to extract just the number using the right, left, function etc in VBA?

So I would want just 1,2,.....34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two easy ways if the left part of the string is static:

1. Replace `times_series_graphs "` with "" :

   ```
   myNumber = Replace(myString, "times_series_graphs ", "")
   ```
2. Use the `Split` function by the character `" "` and keep the second element of the generated array :

   ```
   myNumber = Split(myString, " ")(1)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

### Using the Right function

Because you are only going to 34 you could use the Right/Left function to extract the last two characters and then trim it.

```
Dim yourString As String = "times_series_graphs 1"
Dim numberString As String = LTrim(Right(yourString , 2))
```

This solution quickly falls apart though if you go over two characters since you can't select only the number and blank space anymore. I would recommend one of the following options.

### Tokenizing the string

The first option would be to tokenize your string using the space as the separator. You would split your string on the space and take the second token.

```
Dim yourStringAs String = "times_series_graphs 1" 
Dim tokens() As String = Split(yourString)
```

### Using regex

Another option would be to use Regex. The regex expression below will capture the key in the second group and the value (number) in the third group returned by your regex match.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s([0-9]+)
```

There are a ton of other ways to extract the value as well. For me, I would go with the regex option simply because it provides the most flexibility moving forward. If you get a string that doesn't have the same key before the number, this allows you to quickly access both fields for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the string will contain you can loop through it to find numbers. I think what you are missing is:

```
IsNumeric(myString)
```

This returns a true or false.
The full code for that is here:

```
numberFound = False
For x = 1 To Len(myString)
    temp = Mid(myString, x, 1)
    If IsNumeric(temp) Then
        working = working & temp
    ElseIf numberFound Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
Final = CDbl(working)
```

Beyond that you could use a regular expression.